# How do i activate 'rendered view' in Cycles. Shift z is not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How do I activate rendered view? The hotkey is 'shift z' but this does nothing.

when I press 'shift z' it just goes to wireframe mode.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I am using a mac - blender version 2.9
[image]

Comment: Just press Z. A pie menu will open - rendered is at the top. Or use shortcut Z + 8

Comment: thanks @ChristopherBennett i knew it would be something so simple. (i'm a complete beginner)

Comment: No problem. You can also switch render mode using the 4 circles in the top right (From left to right - Wireframe Preview, Solid Preview, Material Preview, Rendered Preview)

Comment: Shift Z is for shifting between wireframe view and the last used solid view.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>z</kbd> to open pie menu. Rendered view is at top.

[image: Pie menu]

Comment: Once the pie menu is visible you can choose the number (in this case 8 will be rendered mode, so z + 8 will be shortcut to use)